# Prove that $x^d-1$ is a factor of $x^{p-1}-1$ if and only if $d$ is a factor of $p-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does it have anything to do with the fact that when we divide $x^{p-1}-1$ by $x^d-1$, we get a remainder of zero?  Would this mean that $x^{p-1}$ has exactly $p-1$ roots?  Or does that even matter?
This is the first course I've ever taken in abstract algebra and unfortunately the subject isn't quite clicking with me.

Comment: As a start, note that $(z-1)|(z^m-1)$ for any positive integer $m$. Now let $z = x^d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the subject may click more if you think syntactically? here you wish to prove an assertion. since it comes from a field theoretic context the term $x^{p-1}$ occurs in its statement. however what is asserted is clarified and made easier to deal with if you drop what in this context is an irrelevant detail and change the statement of the assertion  to:
$$
x^m-1 | x^n-1  \Leftrightarrow m | n 
$$
this equivalence (if and only if) is thus actually two assertions, which must be verified separately. Marty has given the necessary clue for one direction. from the fact that $t^m-1$ vanishes for $t=1$ it follows that $t-1$ divides $t^m-1$. using the suggested substitution then shows that
$$
m | n \Rightarrow  x^m-1 | x^n-1  
$$
now to go in the other direction.

if $m$ is not a factor of $n$ then we may write $n$ as $km+r$ where $0 \lt r \lt m$. now,
using a mini-telescoping trick, we rewrite:
$$
x^n-1 = x^{km+r} - x^r + x^r - 1 = x^r(x^{km}-1)  + (x^r -1)
$$
if $x^n-1$ were divisible by $x^m-1$, then since we have just shown that $x^{km}-1$ is divisible by $x^m-1$ we must conclude that $x^r-1$ is also divisible by $x^m-1$ which ain't gonna happen.

Comment: +1, Well explained idea. Btw. Why no `LeftRightarrow`?

Comment: i didn't know of it, but thx, i've edited it in

Comment: lhf's proof below is elegant, using only the derivation on $Z[x]$

Answer (score 6):

Here is another proof that
if $x^n-1$ is a factor of $x^m-1$ then $n$ is a factor of $m$.

Write $x^m-1=(x^n-1)g(x)$. Note that $g$ must have integer coefficients because $x^n-1$ is monic.

Take derivatives: $mx^{m-1} = nx^{n-1}g(x) + (x^n-1)g'(x)$.

Evaluate at $x=1$ and get $m = n g(1)$. Since $g$ has integer coefficients, $g(1)$ is an integer and so $n$ divides $m$.

Answer (score 0):

just a footnote, which may show the result more intuitively (this isn't a proof, only an illustration)

you will notice that the quotient $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ is
$$
x^{n-1} +x^{n-2}+\dots+x^1 +x^0 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k
$$
i.e. it has exactly $n$ terms, the first $n$ powers of $x$ beginning with $x^0=1$

now check out:
$$
(1+x^3+x^6)(1+x+x^2) = 1(1+x+x^2) +x^3(1+x+x^2) +x^6(1+x+x^2) \\
=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8
$$
multiplying both sides by $(x-1)$ 
$$
(1+x^3+x^6)(x^3-1)=x^9-1
$$